# How to expand application to work with multiple users and seasons

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say that I have created an app for a school with several models (e.g. Student, Teacher, Course, Attendance, Grade, Timetable, Payments etc).

It's working great for the current year. But now I want to expand my application, so that several schools can use it and it can store data of (mostly) independent seasons/years.

The first solution that comes to my mind, is to add 2 extra models (1)school=user and (2)season=year. And then add ForeignKeys from (almost) ALL my models to both of these (school, season).

(Maybe I could add a third model named SchoolSeason, with just these 2 fields and use this as FK to all my fields.)

Is there a more elegant solution?

Edit: a drawback to this solution would be that the models (e.g. Students) will share their auto-incremented ID with other schools.

Comment: Some code about your current models will help.
But yes, a 'top' model School is helpful. Not necessarily bound to 'user' if you intend to have more than 1 user per school using your app. A model 'season' bound to 'school' is also good.

Comment: Do you want multiple tenancy or shared tenancy? The current situation you have described is a shared tenancy model.

Comment: @DruhinBala shared. I need just one database, having each table once, where I'll host all my clients. I'm open to any other approach, if it's better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without your current models but I would to the same by adding to 2 extra models. But no need to add both of them to all of your models : only Season is needed if you link Season to School.

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    
class Season(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    other_fields...
```

Each Season is linked to a School. Then, you can add the Foreign Key to all of your models.

About your problem in the edit, you are right, it would be a problem. You should not use auto-incremented key but UUid.

Finally, it would look like :

```
class BaseSeasonModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid_lib.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
   
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And all of your models would inherit from it :

```
class Student(BaseSeasonModel):
    ...
```